# Docker container has volume mounted but nginx still serves /var/www/html

Tags: docker, nginx

I created a docker container using

```
sudo docker run --name game-nginx -p 80:80 -v ~/docker-image/html:/var/www/html -d nginx
```

When I ssh into the running docker container I can see the files in /var/www/html

```
drwxr-xr-x  8 1000 1000  4096 Sep 30 17:59  .git
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000  4096 Sep 30 17:59  .idea
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000  4096 Sep 30 17:59  assets
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000  4096 Sep 30 17:59  classes
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   365 Sep 30 17:59  composer.json
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000 77620 Sep 30 17:59  composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000  4096 Sep 30 17:59  css
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000   367 Sep 30 17:59  index.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    17 Oct  1 18:31  info.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000  4096 Sep 30 17:59  js
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000  4096 Sep 30 17:59  lang
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000  4096 Sep 30 17:59  templates
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000  4096 Sep 30 17:59  tests
drwxr-xr-x 16 1000 1000  4096 Sep 30 17:59  vendor
```

I have 1 test file index.html inside the directory /var/www/html and when I browse to localhost in the browser it renders index.html instead of index.php

Nginx is configured correctly because when I copy the files manually into /var/www/html it works. But for some reason I can't mount it using a docker container.

Answer (score -1):

After searching the internet I have no idea what my problem was. But this tutorial fixed it for me: http://geekyplatypus.com/dockerise-your-php-application-with-nginx-and-php7-fpm/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).